# Taking screenshot of desktop in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am newbie to protractor. In my program am taking the screenshot of the current screen using `browser.takeScreenshot()`. But I observed that the screenshot captured does not contain the header of the browser.

Can anyone please suggest how to capture the complete desktop screen image using protractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`browser.takeScreenshot()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.takeScreenshot) on the screenshot you would see only things from the *top-level browser context's viewport* ([WebDriver spec reference](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#take-screenshot)).

One of the possible solutions to the problem and, depending on why do you need the header of a browser on a screenshot, would be to use [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) or [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/start) - both provide the "taking screenshots" capabilities during a test run (and even video recording).